# this._initializeRegions is not a function?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

I tried to learn backbone with marionette .I started learning from this book and make simple program 
**marionette-gentle-introduction-sample.pdf** 
I am getting this error 
**this._initializeRegions is not a function**
here is my codepen
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epvoVm

```
var app =Marionette.Application();

app.staticView=Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    e1:"#main-region",
    template: "#static-template"
})
app.on('start',function(){
    console.log('---')
    var staticView = new ContactManager.staticView();
     staticView.render();
})

app.start()
```

I didn't get any console message but I am getting error on console

**Uncaught TypeError: this._initializeRegions is not a function**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Morning

I'm not to sure on marionette but I believe you need to call a new instance of the application. I tested and it seems to work.

```
var app = new Marionette.Application();
```